# Unity 3D combine texture

Tags: performance, optimization, unity-game-engine, textures, 3d-model

I got a helm, sword and a shield which use 1 texture each, so 3 draw calls. I want to get them to use a single texture to get the draw call down to 1, but not combining them into 1 mesh as i need to disable any of them randomly, plus the sword and shield's position can change when attacking or dropped to ground. Is it doable?

If so how? I'm new to this, thanks.

Comment: I'm on my phone ATM so I can't look at unity but if you click on the image and look in the inspector, i can't remember if this is only for sprites but give it a go, you will see something like "packing tag" or something... Enter a word in there exactly the same for each image and it makes it into a hidden atlas and saves draw calls. Edit: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpritePacker.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save on draw calls, you can use the same material for all three objects without combining their meshes. Then you create a texture file that has the three textures next to each other, and edit the UV maps for the models to use their own parts of the combined texture.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do, and requires what are called Texture Atlases. I believe this is often done as an optimization step with the frequently used smaller textures that comprise a scene.

I don't think the free version of Unity has built in support for this (I might be wrong in assuming that the Pro version does natively support), but I believe there are also plugins - a quick google search found "Texture Packer" that appears to do what you want with the paid version being $15, but there's a free version too, so worth a closer look: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/texture-packer-unity-tutorial.184596/

I don't have experience with any of these yet as I'm not at a stage where I'm trying to do this with my project, but when I get there I think Texture Packer is where I'll start.

Thanks,
Greg